# How to replace my ads on an android app without giving update to a users

Tags: android, admob, android-webview, ads

So i'm completely new to android apps. I have build my own web-view application of my website. I have seen some tutorials on YouTube about putting up Admob in an app but i have few question on that

- If i put Admob code in my app and later if i want to shift to
  another ad company. Do i need to replace it inside my application and
  upload it again in Google play store?
- If yes, then the person who never update an app wont receive my new ad company ads?
- Can we put some code inside the app like we put iframe in html pages from which can change ad codes etc without uploading it again on Google Play Store?

Please answers these question

Thank you

Comment: what you are looking for is admob Mediation. You can have % load of ads defined in an xml on server so you can configure it without update to app. Refer to this link https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation

Comment: so thats the only solution ?

Answer (score 0):

1. **First Solution:** Add mediation to your Admob Ads.
2. **Second Solution:** Fectch a value from database on cloud (ex:[Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/)) and according to that value, setup ads with proper ad network sdk.

**NOTE:**

Both option needs you to integrate another networks SDK or at least mediation adapters just as you imported admob sdk. This leads to increase in app size.

Second option requires you to to extra work.